# Groupwise filtering when not every row is filled

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I don't know if my question fits well in this forum, but I wanted to give it a try. It is about Google Sheets and the Column Filter option. I'm working with a sheet that has the layout as seen below. Is there any possibility of applying a filter to hide all rows for one respective I.D. without repeating the I.D. in the I.D. column for every row? Not repeating the I.D. would keep the sheet much more legible.

| I.D. | Other Columns... |
| --- | --- |
| K2B3D1 | Data for K2B3D1 |
|  | Data for K2B3D1 |
|  | Data for K2B3D1 |
|  | Data for K2B3D1 |
| K2B4D2 | Data for K2B4D2 |
|  | Data for K2B4D2 |

Looking forward to hearing your ideas.

Best
Max

Comment: Of course it can be done with a script. But I wonder as well -- if there is a more native simple way? May be some formula? I don't know.

Comment: I'm not clear on your goal, given only what you show in your post. You only have TWO IDs and you want to hide one set of the two using a column filter? Or do you actually have many different IDs in the first column? And will you only ever be trying to hide ONE ID set? You can best help those of us here to help you if you will share a link to a copy of your spreadsheet. Set the link's Share permission (when creating the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor." And manually enter the results you'd like to see along with an in-sheet explanation of how you'd like the filter to work.

Comment: Also, how will you "instruct" the filter which ID (or IDs) to exclude? Will that be set within a filter formula itself or in some cell (or list contained within some range of cells)? Make this clear in your spreadsheet copy.

Comment: @ErikTyler The first column contains multiple IDs. Just for the sake of simplicity I just wrote down two in my post. I want to have an option that has the same features like the usual column filtering option within GSheets. So that I can click on the Ids from which I want to see the respective data and all others are hidden.

Comment: Column filters cannot work that way. You would need to use "Custom formula is..." in conjunction with the column filter and provide a list somewhere in the sheet for the formula to reference as to which ID groups to include/exclude.

Another option would be to include the ID in every row of A and then use conditional formatting to set the font color of every ID but the first to white; so they would be there, but you wouldn't see them. Then you could use the column filters as you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with pivot table and  filters at the same time:

[image]

Documentation: https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308944?hl=en

i know how do this but if the original data is something this:

[image]

I hope I give you some idea

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. I think it is a neat way, but my sheet is very flexible with an unknown amount of columns. I have to try out whether I could create Pivot Tables without hard coding the range.

Answer (score 1):

If I would make a script I'd propose the algorithm as follows:

1. Apply the usual spreadsheets filters to hide/unhide IDs.
2. Then you can run a script (via custom menu, for example) which finds and hides all the rows with no ID after hidden rows with ID. And vice versa: unhides all the rows after unhidden IDs.

This way it takes just one more click after applying the usual spreadsheet filters.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Since the Sheet should be used daily by other operators and not me, I wanted to have a simple and straight forward solution. However, your idea seems reasonable to me and I'll try that.